# How can I find out, why a Liquibase-migration with Preconditions was MARK_RAN instead of EXECUTED?

Tags: oracle, liquibase, oracle12c, preconditions

I've ran into a problem with a liquibase changeset. The changeset is somehow like that:

```
<changeSet id="recreate-cool-dbobject" author="WTF">
  <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <tableExists tableName="table_a" />
    <tableExists tableName="table_b" />
    <tableExists tableName="table_c" />
  </preConditions>
  <comment>…should be executed if Feature X is available</comment>

  <sqlFile
    path="resources/view-definition-v2.sql"
    relativeToChangelogFile="true"
    dbms="oracle"
    stripComments="false"
    endDelimiter="-- /"
  />

  <rollback>
    <sqlFile
      path="resources/view-definition-v1.sql"
      relativeToChangelogFile="true"
      dbms="oracle"
      stripComments="false"
      endDelimiter="-- /"
    />
  </rollback>

</changeSet>
```

I absolutely know that `table_a`, `table_b` and `table_c` do exists… but still all the time the `view-definition-v1.sql` is executed, and I several times checked if the SQL inside the linked file is valid. If I issue that SQL directly it's executed without any complain.

SQL inside the `view-definition-v1.sql` file is somewhat like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_tab_abc
(
  col_a
, col_b
, col_c
, CREATED_AT
, UPDATED_AT
) AS
SELECT a.id AS col_a
     , b.id AS col_b
     , c.id AS col_c
     , a.created_at AS CREATED_AT
     , a.updated_at AS UPDATED_AT
  FROM tab_a a
  JOIN tab_b b on b.id=a.tab_b_id
  JOIN tab_c c on c.id=b.tab_c_id
WITH READ ONLY
```

SQL inside the `view-definition-v2.sql` file is somewhat like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_tab_abc
(
  col_a
, col_b
, col_c
, CREATED_AT
, UPDATED_AT
) AS
SELECT a.id         AS col_a
     , a.tab_b_id   AS col_b
     , a.tab_c_id   AS col_c
     , a.created_at AS CREATED_AT
     , a.updated_at AS UPDATED_AT
  FROM tab_a a
WITH READ ONLY
```

I already tried `tableName="table_a"`or `tableName="TABLE_A"`, still it's like it is not working at all. I got several other changesets that don't show this problem. Does someone has any clue??

Used Liquibase version is 3.4.2, Database is Oracle 12cR1 StandardEdition1

Thanks for any hint and best regards,
B

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be that it's not looking in the right schema for your tables. Try changing your precondition to have something like this:

```
<tableExists schemaName="my_schema" tableName="table_a" />
```

for each of the checks.

The other thing is that it's always worth saving the generated SQL and running that, using the `updateSQL` parameter if you are using the `liquibase` command. That way you can be sure that the SQL you run is the same SQL that Liquibase runs.